# skimage - crop image according to edges

Tags: python, image, scikit-image

I am trying to crop an image according to its edges
I had something like:

```
imggrey = io.imread(self.input_file, as_grey=True)
edges = canny(imggrey, sigma=self.sigma)
h, a, d = hough_line(edges)
_, ap, _ = hough_line_peaks(h, a, d, num_peaks=4)
cropped = imggrey[ap[0]:ap[1],ap[2]:ap[3]]
plt.imshow(cropped)
plt.show()
```

But obviously i am missing something as the cropped image is nont being generated

can someone help and point me in the right direction?

Comment: `ap` is a list of angles... It does not make much sense to crop an image according to these values. As `ap` is in radians, it most probably in your case has values between 0 and 1, resulting in `cropped` being an empty array. Can you print `ap` to see?

Comment: Yes you are right, i have taken it from another example that doesnt fit the cropping problem, any idea what function should i use instead of the "hough_line_peaks" ?

Comment: An image illustrating what you are trying to achieve would be useful. An image could have many edges. How do you define the edges you want to crop your image along?

Comment: My Target project is to crop the middle image of the airplane : http://media.gettyimages.com/photos/low-angle-view-of-airplane-flying-in-cloudy-sky-picture-id556938483 and then stretch it as much as i would like